# keras import error when kernel has been killed in spyder

Tags: tensorflow, module, keras, spyder

I just started using tensorflow and keras in spyder. I was trying to run a tensor flow example: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification. but when I kill the console and run my code again keras module seems not found and shows the error below

```
    ImportError: cannot import name 'keras'
```

I have installed both keras and tensorflow on my anaconda. I am running this using windows 10 on spyder. the other answer that I have seen on stackoverflow is to install keras which I have done. I have tried to install and reinstall it, it works but after I killed the kernel the error appears again.

I have tried to remove and reinstall tensorflow and keras, it works but then the same problem keep occuring.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 
        'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(300, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)



#-----------------MAKING PREDICTIONS

predictions = model.predict(test_images)
predictions[0]
```

I expect the console will find keras module everytime I kill the kernel or console. my model also got stuck at accuracy of 0.1, this might have no connection to the error but the example shows an accuracy above 0.8

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read [our guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) that explains how to solve this problem.

Comment: which Python version are you using? there must be some kind of Python Interpreter error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, I named my script tensorflow.py